# How can I change the font of a PreText or Paragraph widget?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been trying to change the font of a PreText widget in Python Bokeh, but I failed until now.

I already tried to format the text by using css:

```
pre = PreText(text="text", width=1000, height=500, 
              style={'font-size':'40pt', 
                     'color': 'grey', 
                     'font-weight': 'bold', 
                     'font-family': 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'})
```

But unfortunatelly everything works but 'font-family' doesn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is a bug in Bokeh. As of Bokeh 1.2, the default `font-family` (a Courier monospace) is specified on a `pre.bk` CSS selector, but the styles you provide to `PreText` end up on an enclosing div, so that the `font-family` is overriden. I don't have a workaround to suggest, except to use the `Div` widget instead of `PreText` if you need to control `font-family`.

I'd encourage you to help the project and [file a bug report about this on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and peterh for editing. I will create a bug report on github and try to follow your suggetion.

Comment: As a maintainer of the project it is helpful to use when proeject-tagged questions have accepted answers. An accept would be appreciated.